# Recent posts headlines. How to optimize the loop

Tags: loop, optimization

I'm using this in my page template to display the 20 recent posts headlines from category number 8, 17, 23, 423

```
  <div id="horizontalTab">
   <ul class="resp-tabs-list">
     <li>Football</li>
     <li>Ice Hockey</li>
     <li>Basketball</li>
     <li>Tennis</li>
    </ul>
    <div class="resp-tabs-container">
     <?php $cat_array=array(23,17,8,423);
      foreach ($cat_array as $catid) {
       $args = array( 'category' =>$catid, 'numberposts' => 20 );
       $myposts = get_posts($args); ?>
        <div>
         <?php foreach($myposts as $post) { ?>
         <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a><br/>
         <?php } ?>
       </div>
     <?php } ?>
 </div>
</div>
```

But this code adds more than 15 database queries. Without this code page makes 26 db queries and with it 46. Is it possible to optimize?

Comment: But are the queries _slow_? Hundred lightweight queries might be faster in total than one heavy one.

Comment: Do you require 20 posts from each category, or just 20 posts overall, from the four categories?

Comment: @Rarst, how can I determine it fast or slow? Load time and memory usage are approximately the same in both cases (I mean timer_stop and memory_get_usage functions). Do you think I should not worry about the number of db queries? Sorry for my English.

Comment: Profiling performance is extensive topic. :) Let's put it like this - if you cannot notice/measure significant difference (where "significant" is completely up to you) is it worth spending time on writing more elaborate code for it?

Comment: @Rarst All the fault of the pursuit of excellence and limited my knowledge of php :) I guess you're right :)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of looping through each category and getting the posts for each, you can do it all in one query like this:

```
$categories = array('8', 17, 23, 423);
$args = array( 'category__in' => $categories, 'numberposts' => 20 );
$recent_posts = get_posts($args);
```

Cheers.

Comment: 20 posts from all categories is not the same as 20 posts from _each_ category however.

Comment: That's true but the way I interpreted the question was he wanted 20 posts overall. I will ask for clarification in the comments.

Comment: @StevenJones I want to display the 20 recent titles of the four specific categories